# MySQL GROUP on a column based on other column but also exclude duplicates based on the second column

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have this database

```
+----+-------+--------+-------------+---------------------+------------+---------+
| id | jobid | status | worker      | addedTime           | jobType    | sceneId |
+----+-------+--------+-------------+---------------------+------------+---------+
| 56 | TEST1 |      2 | na          | 2020-02-07 13:19:28 | PROC_STD   | 123test |
| 57 | TEST2 |      2 | na          | 2020-02-07 13:19:29 | PROC_STD   | 123test |
| 58 | TEST3 |     -1 | na          | 2020-02-08 06:45:25 | PROC_STD   | 124test |
| 59 | TEST4 |     -1 | na          | 2020-02-08 06:45:25 | PROC_STD   | 124test |
| 60 | TEST5 |      2 | na          | 2020-02-08 06:55:24 | PROC_STD   | 124test |
| 61 | TEST6 |      2 | na          | 2020-02-08 06:55:25 | PROC_STD   | 124test |
+----+-------+--------+-------------+---------------------+------------+---------+
```

Using

```
SELECT sceneId, COUNT(*) FROM jobqueue WHERE status=2 GROUP BY sceneId, status HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

I can group the sceneId to get this

```
+---------+----------+
| sceneId | COUNT(*) |
+---------+----------+
| 123test |        2 |
| 124test |        2 |
+---------+----------+
```

But I am only interested in sceneId 123test as all rows have status 2 wheras 124test has both status 2 and -1.

Changing the query like this **status!=2** I can atleast get the sceneId I don't want

```
SELECT sceneId, COUNT(*) FROM jobqueue WHERE status!=2 GROUP BY sceneId, status HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

to get this

```
+---------+----------+
| sceneId | COUNT(*) |
+---------+----------+
| 124test |        2 |
+---------+----------+
```

Can the my first query be filtered by the second negating query or are there any other clever tricks to do this i sql?

For clarity I want to change my query to only get sceneIds (could be more than one but in my example there is only one valid result I want) that only have status 2, this is the result I want?

```
+---------+----------+
| sceneId | COUNT(*) |
+---------+----------+
| 123test |        2 |
+---------+----------+
```

I am using                                                                                                             *mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.28, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper*
on Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that, by placing a condition on the `status` in the `where` clause, you eliminate rows before you have a chance to check their content. Instead, you can filter with an another `having` condition that does conditional aggregation:

```
select sceneid, count(*) 
from jobqueue 
group by sceneid 
having count(*) > 1 and min(status = 2) = 1
```

This gives you the list of `sceneid`s that occur more than once and whose all rows have `status = 2`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can achieve your desired results by using an exclusion JOIN.

### Example: [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kvrAbtyW9xggucbLvhBgsX/0)

```sql
SELECT j1.sceneId, COUNT(j1.id) AS dupes
FROM jobqueue AS j1
LEFT JOIN jobqueue AS j2
ON j1.sceneId = j2.sceneId
AND j2.status != 2
WHERE j2.id IS NULL
GROUP BY sceneid
HAVING dupes > 1;
```

**Result:**

```
| sceneid | dupes |
| ------- | ----- |
| 123test | 2     |
```

This works by excluding any records that are matched in the `JOIN` table of those in the `FROM` table with the same `sceneId` that also have a `status` that is other than `2`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a combination of `group_concat` and subquery to get the result you want. Something like this

```
SELECT temp.sceneId, 
       temp.count 
FROM   (SELECT   sceneId, 
                 COUNT(*) AS COUNT, 
                 GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(STATUS)) AS status_filter 
        FROM     jobqueue 
        GROUP BY sceneId ) AS temp 
WHERE   temp.status_filter = 2
```